# Will it hurt if I redirect the desktop version of URL to AMP pages for mobile

Tags: seo, 302-redirect, amp

I run a website. For desktop version we have `https://example.com/listing/india` and corresponding amp pages is `https://example.com/amplist/india`.

When a request comes from mobile, we automatically redirect the desktop version of the page to amppage. Below are the thoughts.

1. Do we need to redirect the page and it is showing as 302 in google webmasters.
2. Else show the amp page in the same url ?

Answer (score 2):

> For desktop version we have https://example.com/listing/india and
> corresponding amp pages is https://example.com/amplist/india.

Compare this your implementation to **[Google recommendation](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls)**:

> Google doesn't recommend Separate URLs as a site setup because it's
> difficult to implement and maintain. Consider Responsive Web Design
> instead.

To answer your questions, check out the info from the same guide:

> Annotations for desktop and mobile URLs To help our algorithms
> understand separate mobile URLs, we recommend using the following
> annotations:
>
> On the desktop page, add a `rel="alternate"` tag pointing to the
> corresponding mobile URL. This helps Googlebot discover the location
> of your site's mobile pages. On the mobile page, add a rel="canonical"
> tag pointing to the corresponding desktop URL. We support two methods
> to have this annotation: in the HTML of the pages themselves and in
> sitemaps. For example, suppose that the desktop URL is
> `http://example.com/page-1` and the corresponding mobile URL is
> `http://m.example.com/page-1`. The annotations in this example would be
> as follows.
>
> Annotations in the HTML On the desktop page
> (`http://www.example.com/page-1`), add the following annotation:
>
> `<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="http://m.example.com/page-1">` On the mobile page
> (`http://m.example.com/page-1`), the required annotation should be:
>
> `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/page-1">` This
> `rel="canonical"` tag on the mobile URL pointing to the desktop page is
> required.